# Are underscores for the CSS IDs and classes in a Rails application a convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've always used hypens in CSS classes and IDs. I've noticed that many Rails plugins (and Rails core) use underscore. I was wondering is this is a convention in Rails application?

I'm confused about what convention for follow because I'm also using ZURB Foundation gem which uses hyphens.

Comment: Rails is a framework, not a religion full of *musts* and *thou shalts* and dogma. If you like hyphens then use hyphens.

Comment: @mu is too short Well, conventions are necessary in order to ease development.

Comment: There is a difference in that in a css selector you can use |= to match portions of an attribute that is hyphenized ie [class|=en] picks out elements with a class of text-en, data-en etc, whereas there isn't an equivalent for _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My venture would be that since hyphens are rarely used for variable names, class names, method names etc... developers out of habit use underscores when naming in HTML and CSS.

I don't believe there is any convention either way though.  Just preference.

Comment: This was my thought too. Most languages I use (Ruby, Python) have an underscore as the best-practice name separator. Sometimes you're dynamically creating classes and IDs so having a standard is practical.

Answer (score 3):

In most editors, the auto-completion function works better if the names include underscores, instead of hyphens. I think this could be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

...consider the hyphens have a mathematical meaning while underscore haven't